# Meaning of "both sides of the viewfinder" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

The text is a description of a camera app that gives its users the feel of the manual lens. Here is a sentence form the text:

> The app is highly useful and allows all kinds of photographers to
>   explore their creativity and offers something special to those **on
>   both sides of the viewfinder**.

I am not sure about the meaning the phrase **on
both sides of the viewfinder**.

I know the lexical meaning of the term "viewfinder". However, I am not sure about the meaning of the said phrase in the given context.

Comment: Could it refer to the photographer and the person being photographed?

Comment: I guess it is one of the possibilities here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that it offers "something special" to both photographers and to models.

Typically, the photographer is behind the viewfinder, and the model is in front. Mobile phone cameras don't have actual viewfinders, so the language is understood figuratively.